# Missing Business Intelligence Project type in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, reporting, service

When I use visual studio 2008 and do a new project I can select the type of project as Business Intelligence project.  From here I can select a report server project.

I noticed that with visual studio 2010, this does not exist any longer. Tried doing some googling about it and got this:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/vsreportcontrols/thread/f2d272b1-a7f5-41b7-9cb8-a0958c192d31

But it may be outdated.  I know this stuff usually comes from SQL Server not Visual Studio, but I have SQL Server 2008 installed as well (Developers edition locally).

So do we have any Visual Studio / SQL Server MS folks that can help with something like this.  I do not want to create a C# report project.

Comment: Just an FYI related ticket: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566937/2008-business-intelligence-projects-ssis-and-ssrs-in-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just read that the SQL team is generally behind the vs.net team.  So you have to use Visual Studio 2008 to develop reports.  I guess the next version of SQL should bring an add on to VS.

See the graph also from MSDN:
[image]

Comment: @mg1075 as of today (June 1st) there is no further update on this.  It is as it is unfortunately.  You will need to use 2k8 to develop the reports.  The next realease should bring reporting to 2010.

Comment: Update - VS2010 can be used with SQL Server 2012 from the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566937/2008-business-inteligence-projects-ssis-and-ssrs-in-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 1):

You need to install SQL Server 2012 with Reporting Services to enable Business Intelligence projects in Visual Studio 2010.
You also need to install SSDT for Visual Studio 2010 to work on the same.