# 2008 Business Intelligence projects (SSIS and SSRS) in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssis

What do I have to install so I can create SQL Business intelligence projects like Report Services reports and Integrated Services packages from Visual Studio 2010?  And will I be able to create solutions that work with both SQL 2005 and SQL 2008?

I attempted to install Business Intelligence Development Studio from SQL 2008 Developer Edition R2 on my client, but it appears grayed out and checked as if already there. From Visual Studio 2010 I don't see how can create these these types of projects.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot edit SQL 2008/R2 projects is VS 2010.

VS 2010 is only compatible with SQL 2012 (and only installed with SQL 2012). VS2008 components are installed by SQL 2008 & 2008R2.

You must use VS 2008 shell to maintain SQL2008 version projects. If you launch VS 2008 on your workstation you should see the SSIS,SSRS, and SSAS project types available.

Comment: *And* you **get** to install VS 2005 to handle packages and reports built under that framework. Convenient, isn't it?