# BIDS for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I have visual studio 2010 installed and SQL Server 2012. i want to create SQL Server Reporting Services in visual studio 2010 but Business Intelligence Project Type is missing from Visual Studio 2010.
Please help me how to include Business Intelligence Project type for Report Service Project in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing Business Intelligence Project type in Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931766/missing-business-intelligence-project-type-in-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 0):

Install Microsoft Sql Server Data Tools, this use to be called BIDS.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843